# Get value of a column based on other column value which is closest to specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list with multiple data frames inside. Each df has the same columns.
I want to know the content of a column(Col1), based on another column (col2). But first I need to know which row within col2 is closest to a specific value.

```
df <- data.frame(DOY= seq(1:365),
                 accum= seq(1, 730, 2))
```

I want to know `DOY` value when `accum` value is closest to 600. And I want to repeat it to every df within the list

I tried:

```
closest<-function(df,sv){
  df[which(abs(df-sv)==min(abs(df-sv)))] }
closest(df= df$acumm, sv= 600)
```

But it works dealing with df and not with lists. Besides the part of knowing DOY value is yet missing.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You can use `lapply(lst1, function(dat) closest(dat$accum, sv = 600))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `{purrr}` would be something like:

```
##solution 
closest <- function(x, value=600) {
  x[which.min(abs(x$accum - value)), ]
}

lst %>% map(closest, value = 600)
```

### for reproduction

```r
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

##data 
n <- 10
df1 <- data.frame(DOY= seq(1, 365, length.out=n),
                  accum= seq(1, 730, length.out=n))

df2 <- data.frame(DOY= seq(1, 365, length.out=n),
                  accum= seq(10, 1000, length.out=n))

lst <- list(df1, df2)

##solution 
closest <- function(x, value=600) {
  x[which.min(abs(x$accum - value)), ]
}

#returs a list 
lst %>% map(closest, value = 600)
#> [[1]]
#>        DOY accum
#> 8 284.1111   568
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>        DOY accum
#> 6 203.2222   560
#returs a df
lst %>% map_df(closest, value = 600)
#>        DOY accum
#> 1 284.1111   568
#> 2 203.2222   560
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>